# Javascript alert on facebook like page

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to show an alert like "You liked the page" when my users click on "Facebook Like Button" in my web site.

I tryed to add onClick="alert("You liked it");" on

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
```

But it dosen't work.

I'm a student sorry for my fail, how i can do it in Javascript?

Thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you've wrapped the text around double quotes. Use single ones instead:

`onclick="alert('You liked it');"`

I will also show you how you can do this in JavaScript:

Firstly you need to give an id to your button so you can reference it in JS:

```
<div id='like-btn' class="fb-like" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
```

Then you can go to your JavaScript file and do the following:

```
var likeBtn = document.getElementById('like-btn');
likeBtn.onclick = function(){
    alert("You clicked it");
}
```

**EDIT:** Facebook provides callbacks for events like, liking a page.

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function() { alert('You liked it'); });
```

You can read more about Facebook Event Subscription [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/v2.6)

Comment: I tryed your solution, but it dosen't work, when i set the facebook code i think it will change with facebook sdk so the id = like-btn it will be lost

Comment: @Dario9494 How about my first recommendation that does not involve an id? Did it work? Also check my edit

Comment: Work fine with the fb event ! Thanks alot